# Hadoop Commands Nor Working

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, installation

I have installed Hadoop 2.6 Single Node Cluster on my Ubuntu 15.04 using [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) site as as reference and I think I have installed it sucessfully.
NameNode and DataNodes are starting up well but when I tried to execute any hadoop commands 
it gives an error
eg hadoop fs -ls gives 
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `.': No such file or directory

But hadoop fs works fine and gives all possibel list of hadoop commands

Comment: I suspect your home directory is missing.Did you try executing an `-ls /`.

Comment: It also gives same warning.
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable ls: `.': No such file or directory.

Comment: Can you try if you can create a home directory for your user. `fs -mkdir -p /user/<user-name>`

Comment: How can I??
none of the hadoop commands are working .

Comment: If you are unable to do any of the above, you should see the namenode and  datanode logs. `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/` should be your logging base path. There is also a namenode and datanode webui in the address  `http://localhost:50070` and `http://localhost:50090` respectively. It should show you the status of the filesystem, services, logs, and filesystem itself. It should help you get going with the troubleshooting.

Comment: The issue is solved now.
The problem was of the 32bit hadoop on a 64 bit environment.
The environment  variables pointing to Hadoop library needed to be changed from 
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/
HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/"
to 
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native"
Thanx a lot for your help @Shyam your answers helped me afterwards :)